# How to "simple" write $k$th derivative of $\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\text{t}_\text{c}+\xi}\Bigr)^\text{p}$

Tags: calculus, notation

I'm struggling with a "notational" problem concerning the "simplified" writing of a formula. I'll give a short example what I mean, considering the $k$-th derivative of
$$
\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigr)^{\text{p}}
$$
where $\text{p}$ and $\text{t}_\text{c}$ are constants. The $k$-th derivative with respect to $\xi$ could be written as
$$
\frac{\text{d}^k}{\text{d}\xi^k}\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigr)^\text{p} = \Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigr)^\text{p}\cdot\Bigl(\frac{1}{\xi}\Bigr)^k\cdot \prod_{n=1}^{k}(\text{p}-n+1)
$$.
My function now is a Little bit different:
$$
\frac{\text{d}^k}{\text{d}\xi^k}\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p} = \dots
$$

Now I try to find also such a "compressed" writing of the $k$-th derivative with respect to $\xi$ like in the example given before. ... But, that's somehow tricky. I see that there's a Kind of pattern behind when I do the derivatives with matlab or Voyage200: The first 3 derivatives (derived with TI Voyage200) are:

$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\xi}\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p} = \Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p}\cdot\frac{\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot\text{p}}{\xi\cdot(\xi+\text{t}_\text{c})}$

$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}\xi^2}\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p} = \Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p}\cdot\frac{\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot\text{p}}{\xi^2\cdot(\xi+\text{t}_\text{c})^2}\cdot-(2\cdot\xi-\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot(\text{p}-1))$

$\frac{\text{d}^3}{\text{d}\xi^3}\Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p} = \Bigl(\frac{\xi}{\xi+\text{t}_\text{c}}\Bigl)^\text{p}\cdot\frac{\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot\text{p}}{\xi^3\cdot(\xi+\text{t}_\text{c})^3}\cdot(6\cdot\xi^2-6\cdot\xi\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot(\text{p}-1)+\xi^2\cdot(\text{p}-2)\cdot(\text{p}-1))$

or with matlab

```
>> diff('(xi/(xi+tc))^p',xi)
ans =

-p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 1)*(xi/(tc + xi)^2 - 1/(tc + xi))

>> diff('(xi/(xi+tc))^p',xi,2)     
ans =

p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 1)*((2*xi)/(tc + xi)^3 - 2/(tc + xi)^2) + p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 2)*(p - 1)*(xi/(tc + xi)^2 - 1/(tc + xi))^2

>> diff('(xi/(xi+tc))^p',xi,3)     
ans =

- p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 1)*((6*xi)/(tc + xi)^4 - 6/(tc + xi)^3) - 3*p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 2)*(p - 1)*(xi/(tc + xi)^2 - 1/(tc + xi))*((2*xi)/(tc + xi)^3 - 2/(tc + xi)^2) - p*(xi/(tc + xi))^(p - 3)*(p - 1)*(p - 2)*(xi/(tc + xi)^2 - 1/(tc + xi))^3
```

... so, the first factor seems to remain always my function; the second factor developes after the rule
$$
\frac{\text{t}_\text{c}\cdot\text{p}}{\xi^k\cdot(\xi+\text{t}_\text{c})^k}
$$
where $k$ is the considered derivative. But I have no idea whats following in these brackets. There seems to be also a rule behind, but I did not yet find out which and unfortunately I can't write this pattern in a mathematical way. Does anyone of you have an idea?

Thank you in advance,
  questionmarkengineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach for computing $\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\frac{x}{x+a}\right)^p$ is just to apply the binomial theorem:
$$\left(\frac{x}{x+a}\right)^p = \left(1-\frac{a}{x+a}\right)^p = \sum_{j=0}^{p}\binom{p}{j}(-1)^j \frac{a^j}{(x+a)^j} \tag{1}$$
immediately leads to:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\frac{x}{x+a}\right)^p &=&  \sum_{j=1}^{p}\binom{p}{j}(-1)^j\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[ \frac{a^j}{(x+a)^j}\right]\\&=&(-1)^k\sum_{j=1}^{p}\binom{p}{j}(-a)^j\frac{(j+k-1)!}{(j-1)!(x+a)^{j+k}}. \tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Uh, I am wondering whether it is applicable for my problem. I forgot to mention that the constants "p" and "a" are doubles and only integers in some special-cases. ... I don't know how the sum (j = 1 ... p) would work with that "restriction".

Comment: @Questionmarkengineer Then replace the factorials with Gamma functions or just use the product form. Indeed, the only step that doesn't "work" is the last one, but on the one before it, you basically need to calculate$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[\frac{a^j}{(x+a)^j}\right]$$Does this look familiar to you? It should, because it happens to be equivalent to something you wrote in your question.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thanks, now it is clear to me!

Answer (score 0):

One might wish to apply [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for the $n$th derivative of a product.

$$\begin{align}\frac{d^k}{d\xi^k}\left(\frac\xi{\xi+t_c}\right)^p&=\frac{d^k}{d\xi^k}f(\xi)g(\xi)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom knf^{(n)}(\xi)g^{(k-n)}(\xi)\\&=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom kn\frac{\Gamma(p+k-n+1)}{\Gamma(p-n+1)}\frac{\xi^{p-n}(-1)^n}{(\xi+t_c)^{p+k-n}}\end{align}$$

where $f(\xi)=\xi^p$ and $g(\xi)=(\xi+t_c)^{-p}$

Comment: Good idea! Thank you! I think that's what I am looking for. ... But, what does the capital $\Gamma$ stand for?

Comment: @Questionmarkengineer The Gamma function. In particular,$$\frac{\Gamma(p+k-n+1)}{\Gamma(p-n+1)}=(p+k-n)(p+k-n-1)(p+k-n-2)\dots(p-n+1)$$This is equivalent to Jack's answer if $p$ is an integer, as we have$$\Gamma(n+1)=n!$$

Comment: @Questionmarkengineer No problem :-)

Comment: I just realized that there might be a typo in your answer: it shoul read $g(\xi) = (\xi+t_\text{c})^{-p}$, otherwise the product does not deliver the original function ...

Comment: Ah, thanks @Questionmarkengineer